# Returning a Java map to to a different class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I have a utility class in my Android application used to hold functions that are reused throughout the app. One of the functions returns a Map of the current logged in users information. When I call this function from an Activity I get no errors but the Map appears to be empty.

Below is the utility class method

```
public static Map<String,String> getUserInfo(String uniqueID)
{

    final Map<String, String> currUserInfo = new HashMap<>();

    final DatabaseReference database =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uniqueID);

    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            currUserInfo.put("user_firstname",user.getFirstName());
            currUserInfo.put("user_secondname", user.getSecondName());
            currUserInfo.put("user_username", user.getUsername());
            currUserInfo.put("user_profile", user.getProfilePicURL());

                     }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return currUserInfo;
}
```

Below is how I am calling the function

```
        userInfo = Utilities.getUserInfo(userID);
```

"userInfo" is declared at the top of the activity as this

```
   private Map<String, String> userInfo;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an Android developer, but by looking at your code I notice you attach a *listener* to the `DatabaseReference` instance. Inside that `ValueEventListener` you `put` the extracted values from `Firebase`.

What might happen is that this *listener* isn't invoked immediatly, but in an asynchronous manner. This means your `getUserInfo` method is allowed to return independently of the `onDataChange` method execution.

This might lead to your `Map<String, String>` being empty after returning.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.